# Не запускается сервер, не может найти модуль

Tags: node.js, express

Столкнулся с проблемой - не запускается сервер по команде npm run dev.
Выдает данную ошибку:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\Артем\Desktop\Диплом\Web-Zen\Server\index.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:889:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:745:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:76:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Файл index.js:

```
const express = require('express')

const PORT = 5000

const app = express()

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log('Server started on port ${5000}'))
```

Файл package.json:

```
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon index.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.1",
    "express": "^4.18.1",
    "pg": "^8.7.3",
    "pg-hstore": "^2.3.4",
    "sequelize": "^6.19.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.16"
  }
}
```

Не знаете как  запустить сервер?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я создал файл index.js вне папки Server - поэтому и не работало.